# Convert Spark DataFrame to float

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have some DataFrame:

```
data=[('Alice',1),('Bob',2),('Alice',5)]
```

and compute a mean value like this:

```
value = dataF.groupBy().mean().collect()
```

result:

```
[Row(avg(age)=2.6666666666666665)]
```

How can I convert it to float? When I use `round` function:

```
print round(value,2)
```

I get `TypeError: a float is required` error.

Comment: `dataF.groupBy().mean().flatMap(lambda x: x).first()`

Comment: Thank you @zero323

Comment: @zero323 Could you explain please, why you need to flatten the mean? I'm pretty new to spark and would like to understand what happens 'internally'.

Comment: @reinka `Row` is a `tuple`. `tuple` is an `Iterable`. Since we `flatMap` with `identity` (`lambda x: x`) it is simply `flatten`. So you get from `RDD[Iterable[float]]` to `RDD[float]`. It maybe an overkill there but it is universal.

Comment: Didn't consider or rather realise that the result after `.mean()` is a tuple. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

value = dataF.groupBy().mean().head()[0]

Comment: Hi @user1842039, am very new to spark , had a question, why does first() work but collect() doesn't ?

Answer (score 1):

For simple conversion, one can do something like

```
val test_df = dataDF.withColumn("xx", $"yy".cast("float"))
```

One can also make use of UDF if in-place conversion is desired. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

value = ( round( float( dataF.groupBy().avg('age').first()[0]), 2) )